# Check mark/ tick mark in javascript for the selected drop-down options onclick show active tickmar

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the selected drop-down options. The selected option should active and tickmark shows at right side of the text.for example I have ten options in my selected drop-down It should active and shows the tick mark when I select each option. Tick mark should remain same for executing  options.

```html
<div id="submenu1" class="p3 sample-submenu">
  <select id="sample" class="form-control" id="select sample">
    <option value="" disabled selected sample> select sample:</option>
    <option value="tv">tv</option>
    <option value="tv">iphone</option>
    <option value="tv">laptop</option>
    <option value="tv">desktop</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Html code:

<div id= 'submenu1' class=" p3 sample-submenu">
<select id =" sample" class ="form-control" id = "select sample">
<option value= "" disabled selected sample> select sample:</option>
<option value="tv"> tv</option>
<option value="tv"> iphone</option>
<option value="tv"> laptop</option>
<option value="tv">desktop</option>
</div>

Comment: Please do not put the code in comments, put it into your question - properly formatted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Also, please go read [ask]. Don’t just tell us what you _want_, but explain what you tried, and what exactly the problem was with that. This site is not a code-writing service, but a place to get help with the code that you _have_ written.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the position of the tickmark, unfortunately, you won't be able to do it out of the box. The tickmark that you see in a standard `<select>` block is added by your OS.

**Mac OS X** adds the the tickmark on the **left** hand side of a selected option, so you will not be able to change it with CSS, unless you do something like [including bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/).

One other thing you could do is converting your `<select>` block to a normal dropdown with buttons and use **CSS** and **JS** to have it working as per your needs.

I have made a playable example below, which manually adds a tickmark on the *right* hand side of the option. Feel free to edit it in order to adapt it to your own needs.

```js
function selectMe(opt) {
  
   if (opt.name == retrieveOption()) return;
   
   document.getElementById("selected").innerText = opt.innerText;

   var children = document.getElementById("content").children;
   
   for (var i of children) {
      var newText = i.innerText.replace(" ✓", "");
      i.innerText = newText;
      i.setAttribute("isSelected", "false"); 
   }

   opt.innerText += " ✓";
   opt.setAttribute("isSelected", "true"); 

   newOpt = retrieveOption();
   document.getElementById("opt").innerText = newOpt;
}


function retrieveOption() {
   var children = document.getElementById("content").children;
   for (var i of children) {
       if (i.getAttribute("isSelected") == "true") {
           return i.name;
       }
   }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.selopt {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #999;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.content a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

.dropdown:hover .content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .selected {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <h2>Select an option</h2>
  <button id="selected" class="selected">Select me!</button>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <a name="opt1" isSelected="false" onclick="selectMe(this)" href="#">Option 1</a>
    <a name="opt2" isSelected="false" onclick="selectMe(this)" href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a name="opt3" isSelected="false" onclick="selectMe(this)" href="#">Option 3</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="selopt">
    <p>Your selected option is:&nbsp;</p><p id="opt"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can obtain the selected option at any time by calling the `retrieveOption()` function. This will allow you to store the selected value into a variable. I have currently set that to retrieve the `name` attribute of your option, however you can set it to return the text, by changing:

```js
return i.name;
```

to:

```js
return i.innerText;
```

And remember to adjust this line (which prevents the tickmark from being displayed in the dropdown "title" when you click on an option multiple times):

```js
if (opt.name == retrieveOption()) return;
```

to this

```js
if (opt.innerText == retrieveOption()) return;
```

Comment: No problem, Prabha! Glad I could help! If I my answer managed to satisfy your request, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)